# Style for Caption in RADGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, caption

How can we set style for caption in radgrid?

Following is how I am trying to set the caption text:

```
radExport.MasterTableView.Caption = "Reports";
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can adjust the styling like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .MasterTable_Default caption {
        color: red;
        }   
    .DetailTable_Default caption {
        color: blue;
        }
</style>
```

Here's some documentation that talks about it:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.gridtableview-caption.html

Comment: You should follow link provided and you should set `CssClass` to `MasterTable_Default` for master `MasterTableView` or/and set `CssClass` to `DetailTable_Default` for every detail tables's `MasterTableView` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add style while only when exporting take a look at [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/design-in-the-caption-header-of-a-grid-on-export)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own HTML code and bind through RadGrid.MasterTableView.Caption at the Export Button Click. It can be a logo or some statement that you would like to have it at the top of the file.

```
string firstHeaderLine = "<div id='master' style='color:black; text-align:left;'>Company Name: XYZ</div>";
firstHeaderLine += "<div id='master' style='color:black; text-align:left;'>Date Report Generated: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "</div>";
firstHeaderLine += "<div id='master' style='color:black; text-align:left;'>Report Generated by: XYZ </div>";
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Caption = firstHeaderLine;
```

Hope this will give you an idea.